# Getting prediction interval for xgboost prediction?

Tags: confidence-interval, boosting

I am looking for a solution that can bring prediction interval for xgboost classification (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), i.e. instead of output the probability that an instance belongs to the class `positive` as a single numeric value, I would like to output a distribution.

I checked some tools such as https://github.com/donlnz/nonconformist or https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3 but I am not sure what tool can be integrated to xgboost.

Might you suggest me some libraries that can bring the confidence to xgboost prediction?

Thanks

Comment: You can always bootstrap your model.